# Elasticsearch match string with spaces, columns, dashes exactly

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I'm using Elasticsearch 6.8, and trying to write a query in python notebook. Here is a mapping used for the index i'm working with:

```
{ "mapping": { "news": { "properties": { "dateCreated": { "type": "date", "format": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy/MM/dd||epoch_millis" }, "itemId": { "type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }, "market": { "type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }, "timeWindow": { "type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }, "title": { "type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } } } } } }
```

I'm trying to search for **exact** string like "[2020-08-16 10:00:00.0,2020-08-16 11:00:00.0]" in "timeWindow" field (which is a "text" type, not a "date" field), and also select by market="en-us" (market is a "text" field too). This string has spaces,colons,commas, a lot of whitecharacters, and I don't know how to make a right query.

At the moment I have this query:

```
res = es.search(index='my_index', 
    doc_type='news', 
    body={
    'size': size,
    'query':{
        "bool":{
            "must":[{
                "simple_query_string": {
                    "query": "[2020-08-17 00:00:00.0,2020-08-17 01:00:00.0]",
                    "default_operator": "and",
                    "minimum_should_match":"100%"
                }
            },
            {"match":{"market":"en-us"}}
            ]
        }  
    }
})
```

The problem is that is doesn't match my "simple_query_string" for timeWindow string exactly (I understand that this string gets tokenized, splitted into parts like "2020","08","17","00","01", etc, and each token is analyzed separately), and I'm getting different values for timeWindow that I want to exclude, like

```
['[2020-08-17 00:00:00.0,2020-08-17 01:00:00.0]'
 '[2020-08-17 00:05:00.0,2020-08-17 01:05:00.0]'
 ...
 '[2020-08-17 00:50:00.0,2020-08-17 01:50:00.0]'
 '[2020-08-17 00:55:00.0,2020-08-17 01:55:00.0]'
 '[2020-08-17 01:00:00.0,2020-08-17 02:00:00.0]']
```

Is there a way to do what I want?

**UPD (and answer):**
My current query uses "term" and "timeWindow.keyword", this combination allows me to do exact search for string with spaces and other whitecharacters:

```
res = es.search(index='msn_click_events', doc_type='news', body={
    'size': size,
    'query':{
            "bool":{
                "must":[{
                    "term": {
                        "timeWindow.keyword": tw
                    }
                },
                {"match":{"market":"en-us"}}
                ]
            }  
        }
    })
```

And this query selects only right timewindows values (string):

```
['[2020-08-17 00:00:00.0,2020-08-17 01:00:00.0]'
 '[2020-08-17 01:00:00.0,2020-08-17 02:00:00.0]'
 '[2020-08-17 02:00:00.0,2020-08-17 03:00:00.0]'
 ...
 '[2020-08-17 22:00:00.0,2020-08-17 23:00:00.0]'
 '[2020-08-17 23:00:00.0,2020-08-18 00:00:00.0]']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `timeWindow` field you need a `keyword aka exact search` but you are using the full-text query and as you defined this field as `text` field and you already guessed it correct, it gets analyzed during the index time, hence you are not getting the correct results.

If you are using the dynamic mapping, then `.keyword` field would be generated for each `text` field in the mapping, so you can simply use `timeWindow.keyword` in your query and it will work.

If you have defined your mapping than you need to add the keyword field to store the `timewindow`, reindex the data and use that `keyword` field in query to get the expected results.

Comment: Thank you Opster. I understand that the best way is to re-index the data. I don't think I can do it (somebody else created it, and people are actively use this db). So may be there is some other way to do exact search on this timeWindow field, without changing mapping or reindexing everything? I'm new to elasticsearch world, may be reindexing is easy thing to do, don't know much about it, but would like to try something less destructive first. If possible, of course.